# ExtJS 4 - Set column tdCls dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, grid, extjs4

I'd like to change the tdCls of a grid column dynamically - hopefully that's possible.

I've set up a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7q5sq/) that contains a grid.  The first column initially has a tdCls of 'bold-column', which just bolds the text in that column.  When you click 'Change Column tdCls' the first column is assigned to the variable `column` but I'm not sure what to do at that point to change the column's tdCls to 'red-column'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the property on your own and refresh the grid view:

```
column.tdCls = 'red-column';
grid.getView().refresh();
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/amitaviv99/7q5sq/2/) is an updated fiddle.